# candelbra base too long, is it safe?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, light

I bought a candelbra bulb that fits correctly in every way except the length of the base:

[image]

As you can see the bulb's base on the right is longer than the one on the left. Is it safe to use the bulb on the right?

When it put it into the lamp, the base sticks out maybe 1mm from the screw-slot (the hole in the lamp where the bulb screws in).

It is okay to use it this way?

Also, the bulb hums sometimes. The lamp is dimmable (the bulb too supposedly) but if I set the brightness to anything other than the minimum or maximum I hear a humming.

So does it all sound about right or I can't use the bulb on the right to replace the bulb on the left?

Thanks.

Comment: That looks like an LED. Is it listed for dimming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the lamp is properly wired, the shell of the socket is connected to neutral. This means that, under normal conditions, the voltage on the shell is minimal vs. ground and so this is generally safe. However, in case of an open neutral or a miss-wired socket with hot on the shell, this could expose lethal voltages.

If this a chandelier which is out of reach, I'd not hesitate to use this bulb. Otherwise, I'd prefer to use a better fitting bulb.

Comment: It's a tall lamp that stands on the ground. Which means that I can't use these bulbs. :(